# ArcGIS Pro: Area of certain land cover types for each main type (simplifiable?)

Tags: arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, statistics, workflow

I have multiple areas with a unique ID (wetland sites) and now want to calculate the area of certain land cover types (grassland, woodland etc.) for each wetland site. I found a solution but am curious if there is a simpler way or a best practice for this use case in ArcGIS Pro:

1. "union" to connect the "unique sites" and "land cover" feature classes to a "union shape"
2. "select by attribute" for land cover class 1 (e. g. "grassland") in the "union shape"
3. "Field statistics" -> Sum of Shape Area for "unique site ID" in the selection of the "union shape"
4. Join the output table with the "union shape"
5. Use field calculator to copy the Sum of Shape Area from the output table into the "union shape"
6. Do steps 2-5 for each land cover class.

I already thought about exporting the "union shape" as a table and doing the rest with R but is there a simpler way in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this work flow by using the summary statistics tool on your Union data and setting the case parameter to your vegetation type AND site ID.

An error that is easy to do is to use the area field from the source layers in the union result. Union carries over all fields from the source layers, including the original area values.  You should create a new numeric field after your union step and compute the new area and it is that field that feeds into the summary tool.

You then use the [Join Field](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/join-field.htm) tool to permanently join fields from your summary results into source layers.

All what I have mentioned above could be very easily built in model builder to automate future processing.